# Sprint Data Rest extend PagingAndSortingRepository with custom method

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest

My objective is to add a custom convenience method to a Spring Data REST API without creating my own controller.

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) I have extended `PagingAndSortingRepository` in the following manner:

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface PartyRestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Party, String>, CustomPartyRestRepository {
}
```

Interface with my method:

```
public interface CustomPartyRestRepository {
    void dynamicPartyCreation(final String name);
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class CustomPartyRestRepositoryImpl implements CustomPartyRestRepository {
    @Autowired
    private PartyService partyService;

    @Autowired
    private PartyRepository partyRepository;

    @Autowired
    private HeroService heroService;


    @Override
    public void dynamicPartyCreation(final String name) {
        final Party party = this.partyService.createParty(name);
        final List<Hero> heroes = IntStream.range(0, 3)
                .mapToObj(i -> this.heroService.createHero(String.format("Hero %d for %s", i, name)))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        party.setMembers(heroes);
        this.partyRepository.save(party);
    }
}
```

When I do `GET localhost:8080/profile/parties/`, I see that Spring has picked up my method and is exposing it:

```
  <...cut...>
  {
    "name": "dynamicPartyCreation",
    "type": "SAFE"
  }
   <..cut..>
```

But I can't seem to use it. `GET localhost:8080/parties/dynamicPartyCreation/` results in 404, as does POST, with body or without, with query param or not. A `PUT` simply creates a party and ignores the `/parties/dynamicPartyCreation/` part of the url (meaning, my method isn't called). I have tried a million combinations but I can't use it.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share your controller detail from where you are calling localhost:8080/profile/parties/ and GET localhost:8080/parties/dynamicPartyCreation/

Comment: That's provided by spring data rest, I didn't implement any controllers

Comment: This  is a very strange solution. What exactly is the problem you are trying to solve with this code? Couldn't this more easily be handled more easily via the SDR events system? https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-rest-events Spring Data Rest

Comment: It's a plain old spring data rest api. For convenience, additional endpoints should be exposed that do common sequences of operations in one go. In this example, creating a party with four heroes attached to it, thus reducing 9 calls into one).

Answer (score 0):

Well, interesting, I never thought it could work this way...

try

```
return this.partyRepository.save(party);
```

Although I don't understand how can it work at all, when you basically @autowired PartyRepositoryCustom into itself...

So maybe it should be something like this:

```
public class CustomPartyRestRepositoryImpl implements CustomPartyRestRepository {

@Autowired
private PartyService partyService;

@Autowired
private ListableBeanFactory beanFactory;

@Autowired
private HeroService heroService;


@Override
public Party dynamicPartyCreation(final String name) {
    final Party party = this.partyService.createParty(name);
    final List<Hero> heroes = IntStream.range(0, 3)
            .mapToObj(i -> this.heroService.createHero(String.format("Hero %d for %s", i, name)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    party.setMembers(heroes);
    return beanFactory.getBean(PartyRepository.class).save(party);
}
```

}

If the server doesn't start, try accessing/initialising the PartyService and HeroService via beanFactory too.

Although it should work (I successfully tested a similar method in my current project), I still don't think it's a good idea to implement it this way.

1. It's not a search (even if it returns a new object)
2. It changes the DB, so this endpoint should be accessed via PUT method.

So I suggest creating a custom controller method instead, and moving the logic into the PartyService class.

Oh, btw. The URL you were looking for is

```
GET /parties/search/dynamicPartyCreation/
```